# Recursive function in C to find arithmetic combinations for any number N

Tags: c, math, recursion

I am in the process of learning C. My question is the following: Given a series of number

1 *+ 2 *+ 3 *+ 5 .... *+ 9

or

Where a number n can be created by any combination any of the digits 1 to 9 via either adding, multiplying, or both, for example:

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 = 60486

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 45

Obviously, there are a collection of numbers which can be represented through various combinations of the above. My recursive function should return how many different unique representations a number N has in the above format.

Thus far, I have been working around the solution like this:

```
int recCheckSolutions(int n, int idx, int tree[], int cnt, int sum)
{
    if (n == sum)
        return 1;
    if (idx > 9)
        return 0;
    if (sum >= n)
        return 0;
    cnt += recCheckSolutions(n, idx + 1, tree, cnt, sum += idx);
    cnt += recCheckSolutions(n, idx + 1, tree, cnt, sum *= idx);
    return cnt;
}
```

Function is called as such:

```
int solutions = recCheckSolutions(n, 0, tree, 0, 0);
```

where n is the desired number we want to find combinations for
sum is the integer variable used to see where we are at in our calculations
and tree[] is an implementation of a tree I was using to check which numbers have been calculated (obviously no longer relevant in this implementation, but still could be useful?)

It has some of the correct behavior, I've done a stack trace/debug and it seems to have some of the solution, however, it isn't terminating with the correct result. It's very possible I'm barking up the wrong tree .

Thank you very much for your feedback and help.

Comment: Why this check `if (n == sum) return 1;`

Comment: if (n==sum) returns true if we've managed to count up to our desired number, which is n. So if I call this function, "n" is the number I want to find combinations for

Comment: Is it correct that `sum += idx` modifies `sum`, such that in the next call `sum *= idx` is actually `(sum+idx) *= idx`?

Comment: I think so, depending on how the recursion continues to execute, whether it returns to the second recursive call (sum *=idx) or the first one (sum+= idx)
Although, that is not directly intended. It needs to continue calculating while idx < 9

Comment: You are just counting the number of possible combinations of + and * between 9 digits here, i.e. 2 to the power of 8, or 256. If you want to calculate the actual values of the expressions you have to take operator precedence into account, e.g (1+2)*3... is not the same as 1+(2*3)...

Comment: how about `1+2+3*4*5+6+7*8+9` is legal as well?

Answer (score -1):

You have got the most of the things right except the return conditions:

```
int recCheckSolutions(int n, int idx, int tree[], int cnt, int sum)
{
    if (idx == 9)
        return 1;
    cnt += recCheckSolutions(n, idx + 1, tree, cnt, sum += idx);
    cnt += recCheckSolutions(n, idx + 1, tree, cnt, sum *= idx);
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I understand how this could work, but how is the "cnt" variable incremented if the function can only return 0? 
This is why I had the condition sum == n

Comment: It is not true that the function can only return 0,   it can also return cnt.

Comment: I see that it can return cnt, but somewhere within the function, doesn't cnt need to be incremented? The idea is cnt is incremented WHEN sum == n
n is our number we're trying to find combinations for, sum is the result of our last operation.

Comment: I ran the code and it will always return zero because at the deepest level of recursion it will return zero and nothing will modify that value.

Comment: It seems to return an absolutely huge number when I add the n == sum condition. Have no idea why...